How to handle a campaign where the players are trapped inside a monster controlled by another player?
I'm creating a custom campaign to play with my brothers, where they will be people trapped inside a monster. They will travel across different sections of his body, looking for a way of exit. The monster will be controlled by another player, who will have his own adventure. The problem comes from the fact that I want to run the campaigns in parallel, at the same time, in the same session. The idea is that both stories interact and provide feedback to each other. For example, if the monster eats something, the other players could go to his stomach and take the food or object. Or if they damage one of his organs, it would damper the monster's capabilities. I really like the idea but Im not sure of how to implement it. I searched if someone has done something similar but at best I found how to handle temporary split parties (in my case, it is permanent). So my question is: what can I do to make this campaign fun, without annoying or confusing my players?
Things to consider:

We will use the system “Fate accelerated”
I want to do a short campaign (2-3 sessions)
The campaign will be a comedy, with an absurd story
It will have battles, but only a few and preferably not 2 at the same time
The monster will be similar to Kirby in personality and powers
There will be a way of communication between the monster and the people inside, but it won't be always available


Your brothers are in for a lot of fun and laughs I reckon. :) It made me giggle as it reminded me of South Park's Lemmiwinks Story! xD

Sometimes, the Bronze Rule gets real literal.

In Fate, you can treat anything in the game world like it’s a character. Anything can have aspects, skills, stunts, stress tracks, and consequences if you need it to.
-- 'Extras: The Bronze Rule' from the SRD

So Bowser* has consumed Mario and Luigi in a magic vortex and now they're tiny-sized and running around his weirdly cosmopolitan insides, looking for a way out. As a result of this, every scene that features Bowser in it also has Mario and Luigi in it, just small and inside him and not really capable of affecting anything except Bowser (but boy, can they affect Bowser if they jump on or hammer the right things). And similarly, every scene that features Mario and Luigi in it also features Bowser as the landscape on which it all takes place.
So you can use the standard Fate rules for structured challenges or contests to run a scene where Bowser has to make a big jump and Mario and Luigi need to supercharge his leg muscles to do it, or where Mario and Luigi are trying to find some piece of knowledge in Bowser's brain and Bowser is trying real hard not to think about Peach so the path doesn't get reshuffled. (Strictly speaking they're not part of Fate Accelerated, but Fate Core and Fate Accelerated are not different games.)
Or even if you don't use a structured play element, there's every justification here for one side to Create an Advantage that affects the other, using the basic Fate means of establishing a true thing with a bonus attached for using it.
*yes, I'm aware you're basing this off something different, but I need to put some names to this scenario where one guy has eaten two other guys and those ones are just calling to me
Plot and Framing Considerations

Avoid deliberate antagonism. Not because Fate can handle it but because it has to pass through you the GM as a medium. There's no simple numeric target at play here - it's your call how much Mario and Luigi roughing something up actually does to Bowser, and it's your call how much Bowser doing a headstand or eating a weird thing does to Mario and Luigi. Besides, most of the fun of this setup is that you're probably setting things up through a Trouble or Issue aspect for one character to accidentally make the others' lives more complicated, and if your players are already throwing hands that'll lose a lot of its uniqueness as a plot twist.
Communication and awareness aren't the same thing. It's fine to limit actual communication between the big guy and the little guys, but you're all there sitting at the same table, you can't just pretend that somebody didn't hear you set up the scene on the outside/inside of Bowser. So lean into it a little, because again, you're going to either be setting these people up to work unknowingly together or unknowingly at cross purposes (with some fate points for consolation).
Always dual-frame if you can. Because the characters are constantly present in each others' lives, you're not going to have extended periods where half of your split cast is in a scene alone. They always have the potential to interact with each other, so even if you're focusing on one side or the other you should always at least frame the other side, if only just to show them doing something unremarkable or that will take a long time.
If you're looking for an excuse for communication, may I suggest a dream? Have Bowser project himself inward when he falls asleep and run around his own insides with Mario and Luigi. Maybe fight some of the weird things his sleeping mind conjures up, and of course when he wakes up again he might be resolved to do a certain thing, but it was all just a dream, right?



What can I do to make this campaign fun, without annoying or confusing my players?

This is going to be difficult.
Spotlight Time
The first concern that springs to mind is what I've come to think of as the "Cyberpunk Netrunner" problem.
The Netrunner is Cyberpunk's hacker: their job is to break into the computer systems and help the rest of the party do their thing (eg., by opening doors, controlling elevators, etc.). The problem is that, especially in some versions of the game, they can easily be wholly disconnected from the rest of the party - it's not hard to 'run from the other side of the planet - and they're often on a whole different map. I've been in campaigns where the 'runner is twiddling his thumbs while the rest of the party was doing stuff in meat-space, then they were all twiddling their thumbs while I was hacking the mainframe; in both cases, there was precious little that one group could do to affect the other (sure, I could open doors now and then, but I was mostly fighting the network while the rest of the party was fighting the physical security, on different maps and at different time scales).
Those sessions d..r..a..g..g..e..d. They dragged to the point that, when we ran another Cyberpunk campaign years-later, we decided to make the 'runner an off-screen NPC and just have the GM roll dice to see how much help they could provide.
This "in the monster" campaign you're proposing, as you've laid it out, is entirely 'runner sessions. There are two games going on, with limited points of intersection or ability to affect the other. While the monster player is in the spotlight, the other players can twiddle their thumbs or start playing on their phones without feeling like they're going to miss anything that affects them, and vice-versa. One resolution to that is to give both groups roughly-equal spotlight time - so neither group can zone out - but that gives the one monster player significantly more spotlight time than any of the other players; on the other hand, evening out the spotlight time among all the players gives the monster player plenty of time to scroll Reddit on their phone.
Communication

There will be a way of communication between the monster and the people inside, but it won't be always available

How strictly do you want to enforce that communication only happens through this intermittent mechanism? Enough to have the groups in different rooms when the mechanism isn't being used?
If you do separate the groups, the one you're not sitting with will be bored and start playing on their phones. If you don't, the groups will use information that they "don't have" - they can't not, because they're humans. I don't know how important that is for the story you have in mind, but it's something to consider.
Allies, Enemies, or Other?
Is the monster trying to defeat the other players or are they supposed to be working together to overcome some other obstacle?
An antagonistic relationship magnifies the communication problem (at least, to my mind), since each group will want to make sure that the other can't hear their plans. It also means that they'll be making plans, which will give the other side (especially the monster side) time to go play on their phone while there's nothing to do. Also, this could pretty easily lead to IRL hurt feelings; just be aware.
A friendly relationship might help: the groups are less likely to want to create secret plans, so it's easier to talk more freely and pay attention to the other group's discussions. But, that also magnifies the "using information they shouldn't have" problem.
What does that mean for me?
I love the idea of a comedy happening in a monster. I have a lot of reservations about the "and the monster is another PC" part of it. If you want to keep the "monster as PC" element, I strongly recommend selecting a player who you know well and know will be able to handle being off on their own for meaningful swaths of time while the "inside" group is doing stuff.
The monster player needs to be able to make decisions quickly and entertain themself when they're not in the spotlight. They also need to be able to make decisions that are sensical for them without unduly screwing over the players inside them. And, if their relationship is meant to be antagonistic, needs to expect to lose and be good with that. That really, really sounds like the purview of a GM rather than a player, but: if you've got a player who can fill that role, it might just work.

Thanks. We want to have a friendly relation between the monster and other players. And about the screentime, I was planning to handle it equally among everybody, although now I see that the monster player may disconnect when the actions of the group inside don't affect him directly. I need to rethink that.

@AlexisMercado "equal" time won't be equal. If you'll have 4 players inside, they all will have some opportunity to try to act for the ⅘ of time. So each of them will only be out of action for ⅕ of the time, really, and the monster player will be out for ⅘.

Given that it's only 2-3 sessions, and given that (presumably) you won't be able to try out different techniques in advance to see what works, I think the main route around "this is going to be difficult" is that you need to manage expectations and ensure the players will be patient. If they go in with an expectation that everyone is entitled to an absolutely fair share of spotlight time, then you're stuffed, because you're not going to be that accurate. Calculating what that fair share is won't even get you close to achieving it.

... the main thing is that each player needs to be invested in what is happening in the narrative that their character is not involved in. One way is to somehow make it interesting to them as spectators, making spotlight time less essential to fun. This sucks for a long campaign but can be OK for a short time. Another is to make them participants, with one or more secondary characters. For example the players of the team could take on NPCs at monster-level. The monster player could perhaps play its own immune system.

"the "using information they shouldn't have" problem" - again this could perhaps be addressed by managing expectations. Some hypothetical extremist players would refuse to play a game in which they know anything that their character doesn't. For a short comedy game, honestly it's easier to be funny the more you know. If you go to see a live improv troupe, you'll note that they don't leave the stage or cover their ears when they aren't "in scene" yet. You could tell them they're going to be playing with OOC knowledge and encourage them to make the most of that.

Or in short: go to the players, say "this is an odd experimental concept, it might fail or it might be brilliant, but it is what it is. Do you want to try it?". Once they all say yes, they're invested in making it work, over making it tick every single box that a more standard campaign would tick. Once you've established that they're using OOC info to set up comedic pitfalls, the main party PCs in-character don't even need to know they're in a monster.
